# How do I make a file check another file data real time and not cached from the start

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an If statement that checks if data from another file is equal to data from its own file... However if the data in the other file changes the data the if statement sees doesnt... Here is an example
Example.json:
`"Names": [{"name": "Tyler"},{"name": "Jeff"}]` 
Example.js :

```
` const example = require("./Example.json");
if(example.Names.find(n => n.name === "Tyler")=== "Tyler"){console.log("what up")} else{console.log("nothing");}; `
```

But say I change Tyler in Example.json...
`"Names": [{"name": "Joe"},{"name": "Jeff"}]` 
The if statement in Example.js still would print "what up".

Comment: Can you share more of the code? Where are you reading the file to begin with?

Comment: Sure... I am using node... I will edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`require` is designed to cache the `exports` object](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/), so you should not use it if the file is going to be updated at runtime.

Instead, you should use [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) whenever you want to access the file's content.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function parseJSONFile(filepath, callback) {
  fs.readFile(
    filepath, 
    { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' }, 
    function (err, file_content) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(file_content);
          callback(null, json);
        } catch (e) {
          callback(e)
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**Usage**

```js
parseJSONFile('./Example.json', function(err, json) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle the error
  } else {
    // Use json object
  }
});
```

Comment: I already use fs to write the file.. I feel dumb now not using it to read the file... Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.